# Angular http post to Laravel backend Request always empty

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a problem that i don't know how to solve.
I use AngularJS 1 to make a post to my backend (Laravel 5.1).
The post is successful from AngularJS.

In my Laravel controller i use Request to recieve the posted data from AngulrJS but the $request->all() is always empty and i dont know why.

I have i missed something in my post request?

```
LARAVEL ROUTE:

Route::post('/signup','SignupController@Signup');


LARAVEL CONTROLLER:
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
    public function Signup(Request $request){


       dd($request->all()); <-- is always empty
    }  
}
```

ANGULARJS POST:

```
.controller('SignupCtrl',function($scope,$http,$state){ 

  $scope.Signup = function($params){

        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        $http.post('http://localhost:8888/vemhamtar/public/signup',{"name":$params.name,"phone":$params.phone,"email":$params.email,"password":$params.password})
        .success(function(response){

          $params.name = "";
          $params.phone = "";
          $params.email = "";
          $params.password = "";
          $state.go("app.contacts");

        })
        .error(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        });
  };
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$httpParamSerializer` to format your payload as url-encoded form data.

```
.controller('SignupCtrl',function($scope,$http,$state,$httpParamSerializer){ 

    $scope.Signup = function($params){

        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        $http.post('http://localhost:8888/vemhamtar/public/signup',$httpParamSerializer({"name":$params.name,"phone":$params.phone,"email":$params.email,"password":$params.password}))
        .success(function(response){

            $params.name = "";
            $params.phone = "";
            $params.email = "";
            $params.password = "";
            $state.go("app.contacts");

        })
        .error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
})
```

Comment: Awsome!! Thank you so much!